# Dynamically creating object causing freezing and not responding in QT Qml

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

I have to call a heavy qml file but when I use code given by Qt in docmentation then my application freezes and also go to not reponding state for some second.

```
 property var component;
function createSpriteObjects() {

    component = Qt.createComponent("qrc:/qml/called.qml");
  
    if (component.status === Component.Ready)
      {  
        finishCreation();
    }
    else {
        component.statusChanged.connect(finishCreation);
    }
}

function finishCreation() {
   
    if (component.status === Component.Ready) {
    
        var sprite = component.createObject(callingwindow);
       
        if (sprite === null) {
            // Error Handling
            console.log("Error creating object");
        }
    } else if (component.status === Component.Error) {
        // Error Handling
        console.log("Error loading component:", component.errorString());
    }
}
```

Comment: My guess is it has something to do with whatever is in `called.qml`. Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: yes it is calling lot of qml files and many more components

Comment: please provide a [mRe]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **QCoreApplication::processEvents();**

The event loop is started with a call to exec(). Long-running operations can call processEvents() to keep the application responsive.